# (0, _.combineReducers) is not a function REDUX, REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

i´m developing an app in react native (expo) and I'm using redux and react navigation so far I am doing the project architecture and it throws me this error

```
TypeError: (0, _.combineReducers) is not a function. (In '(0, _.combineReducers)({
    title: titleReducer,
    version: versionReducer
  })', '(0, _.combineReducers)' is undefined)
```

This is the part where it says the error is

```
// @packages
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

// @scripts
import { SET_APP_TITLE } from './actions';
import { config } from '_config';

/**
 * @returns {string}
 */
const titleReducer = (
    state = config.initialState.appInfo.title, 
    action
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_APP_TITLE:
            return action.payload;
        case 'LOGOUT':
            return 'login';
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

/**
 * @returns {string}
 */
const versionReducer = (
    state = config.initialState.appInfo.version, 
    action
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const appInfoReducer = combineReducers({
    title: titleReducer,
    version: versionReducer
});
```

later there is another page where I call this constant **appInfoReducer** and mount that on another reducer etc ... if it is necessary that I send more info of the code I am pending.

Thank you.

Comment: don't think the error is in this part of the code.

Comment: Agreed, I would look for somewhere where you might have accidentally used a default import instead of a named one.  If you have `import combineReducers from 'redux';` somewhere then you would get this error.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I just call the combineReducers here [link](https://github.com/angeldavidhf/conaliados-app/blob/master/src/redux/index.js) and here [link](https://github.com/angeldavidhf/conaliados-app/blob/master/src/redux/app/reducers.js)

Comment: @HaraldGliebe this is the project repository [link](https://github.com/angeldavidhf/conaliados-app)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen this before and I'd assume that you have multiple versions of Redux in your node_modules. Probably 4.0.5 and 4.1.0. Try to make your package manager only install one of them. If you are using yarn, with the `resolutions` entry in the `package.json`, with other package managers you'll probably have to ressearch.

Another possible reason that comes to mind is that you could have a circular import somewhere in your code.

Comment: I already tried to delete node_modules and cache but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you do a `npm ls redux` or `yarn why redux` to make sure there is only one version?

Comment: throw this 
`+-- react-redux@7.2.4
| '-- @types/react-redux@7.1.16
|   '-- redux@4.1.0  deduped   
'-- redux@4.1.0 `